# calculate sum with criteria from many columns of another filtered table DAX PowerBi

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

Hello i want to sum a column but i need to filter the table based on data from another table.

So i have table1 where i want to sum points and i want to sum only the record that for the dates and the names and the classes i find in table 2

[image]

I am using measure like this:

```
Measure 3 = CALCULATE(sum(Table1[points]);Table1[name] in (ALLSELECTED(Table2[name]));Table1[date] in (ALLSELECTED(Table2[date]));Table1[class] in (ALLSELECTED(Table2[class])))
```

but it does not filter properly,

is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be, you create a relationship between the two tables. I think Power BI doesnt support multi relationships between two tables, so you have to add a custom column on both tables with your key <> foreign key. In your case like you mentioned it woulb be the name, date and class (in the query editor):

```
Key = [name] & [date] & [class]
```

In my sample here I just use the name as key column.

[image]

If the relationship is set you can use the following measure:

[image]

Comment: Power BI now allows many to many relationships. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @jeffbricco I think he meant is a relationship cannot be defined on more than one columns from both tables in power bi, that is why he came up with the concatenated column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TREATAS to filter Table1 based on Table2. No relationship is needed.

```
Total Points Filtered By Table2 = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[point] ),
    TREATAS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Table2, Table2[name], Table2[date], Table2[class] ),
        Table1[name], Table1[date], Table1[class]
    )
)
```